Can we test injection attacks in API parameters with Zap?
Can we test injection attacks in API parameters with Zap tool?
With Zap I am trying to scan APIs. Provided Bearer token with a script and Swagger API definition file. I am getting results related to weak Certificates and Transport headers vulnerabilities.
My expectation was something kind of testing API parameters with injection attacks and results like SQL or command injection type of vulnerability
Does Zap tool has this capability?


ZAP hasn't been a OWASP project for almost a year now. (It didn't end-up joining the SSP, but still here's the announcement: https://www.zaproxy.org/blog/2023-08-01-zap-is-joining-the-software-security-project/)
Yes ZAP can and does perform injection attacks (assuming your run an Active Scan). For more info see:


https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/how-can-you-use-zap-to-scan-apis/
https://www.zaproxy.org/blog/2017-06-19-scanning-apis-with-zap/


what about api parameters? Does it perform injection or input validation attacks on the parameters of APIs? I did not get results as such from my scan

Depends what type of params you're talking about. ZAP "can" attack anything you should need to but depending how you run your scan they might not be the default options. https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/ui/dialogs/options/ascaninput/
